How to import the style file of primeng v18 version? The file was not found
How to import the style file of primeng v18 version? The file was not found.
Angular v18 can use primeng v18 and correctly import style files
enter image description here
app global setting has added,but it's not work,help me
app global setting has added,but it's not work,help me
